# Session variables & cookies disappearing in IE when going from https to http page

Tags: php, session, cookies, https

On an Apache server, I have set of Profile pages within a folder protected by htaccess (/main/profile). After a user updates their profile, I want to set a $_SESSION['timelineuser']= or a session cookie for use back in the main folder of the site (/main/) which is unsecure.

On the unsecure page I want to check to see if $_SESSION['timelineuser'] exists. Works fine in Firefox, Chrome, etc. In IE8, the behavior is bizarre - the $_SESSION (and cookie in my other tests) doesn't show up when you click on the http:// link back to the main page after updating your profile. However, *if you refresh the browser it does show up*.

It has something to do with how I link from the secure page. If I have an href="/main/index.html" it works but throws security warnings. If I have an href="http://www.foo.com/main/index.html" (where I want it to go) in IE there ia a brief blank screen before the main page loads.

Something to do with going from https to http?

Comment: Try adding a random query variable/value to the link, e.g. `href="/index/main.html?cachebuster=<?php echo time() ?>"`, which should force to the browser to request a fresh copy of the page instead of just serving up the cached copy.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. From my experience, cookies set on a subdomain 'www.mydomain.org' are not always accessible on the top level domain 'mydomain.org'. I always recommend clients to never supply the 'www.' in domains, paths etc when installing blog packages etc, because then f.ex. a webshop backend I code will only be able to access 'www.' cookies if navigated to from a URL containing 'www.', ie. 'www.mydomain.org/webshop/index.php'.

Marc's suggestion is excellent for content that must never be stale btw, say stuff on a login page or re-uploaded pictures with the same filename - just slap on a randomly generated string like his to an img src="avatar.jpg" :)